# Javascript value not changing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to get the total value coming from an observable array, it will always come with the value of zero. Any ideas on how to make variable totalPago have the total amount for the array? thanks in advance!

```
var totalPago = 0;
var totalDosmil = 0;
var totalMil = 0;
var totalQuinientos = 0;
var totalDoscientos = 0;
var totalCien = 0;
var totalCincuenta = 0;

var totalRegistro = data["resultado"].length;
self.listaReporte(data["resultado"]);

$.each(data["resultado"], function (key, item) {
  totalPago += item.MontoPagado;
  item.MontoPagado = item.MontoPagado.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
  totalPago.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');

  totalMil += item.Denominacion.mil;
  totalQuinientos += item.Denominacion.Quinientos;
  totalDoscientos += item.Denominacion.doscientos;
  totalCien += item.Denominacion.cien;
  totalCincuenta += item.Denominacion.cincuenta;
  self.listaReporte.push(item);
});

self.TotalPagado(totalPago.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
self.tMil(totalMil);
self.tQuinientos(totalQuinientos);
self.tDoscientos(totalDoscientos);
self.tCien(totalCien);
self.tCincuenta(totalCincuenta);
```

Comment: Is your `each` function really iterating over an array? Is the `formatMoney` method really in place on the Number prototype?

Comment: Yes it is, because i get the other values. but the total Amount won't show.

Comment: It seems like this should be straightforward to check out in the dev tools debugger then.  Do you see `item.MontoPagado` having a non-zero value and the `totalPago` value incrementing in the loop?

Comment: even with the debbuger i won't get anything.. it's really weird.

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer. Could you at least show us the data["resultado"] format?

Comment: can i use a link to paste the result? it's too long : https://pastebin.com/m9F5dW6r by the way, the total amount i want is in the result, called MontoTotalRedondo. but i don't know how to get it.

Comment: This all seems to work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/wz3n8xaq/. I'm guessing you've got some script error or undefined symbol you're trying to use that you're ignoring and which is keeping the each loop from actually running.